# How do I have all section titles, etc bold-faced, in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, context

I'm just experimenting with ConTeXt.  At the moment, all my `\section` and `\subject` headings are appearing in large type.  But I'd like them (and the `\section` numbers) all in bold-face.

I've tried

```
\setuphead[textstyle=bold,numberstyle=bold]
```

and

```
\setupheads[textstyle=bold,numberstyle=bold]
```

but neither of these have any effect.

Can anybody advise me on the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define which type of headings the formatting should affect:

```
 \setuphead[section,subject][numberstyle=bold,textstyle=bold]
```